# JQuery Validation - Email validation not valid if user appends a space...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the JQueryvalidation library which causes an error message when performing validation with the email rule when the user appends a space to the input field. How can I prevent this behavior in order to not prompt the user with an error message?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the validation code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Registration Form Validation
    var validator = $("#registerForm").validate({

        rules: {
            //Registration Form Validation
            "register[fullName]": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                maxlength: 48
            },
            "register[email]": {
                required: true,
                email:true,
                maxlength: 64
            },

        },

        messages: {
            //Registration Form Validation
            "register[fullName]": {
                required: "Full Name Required."
            },
            "register[email]": {
                required:"Email Required",
                email:"Please enter a valid email."

        },

        errorPlacement: function(error, element){
            error.appendTo(element.parent());
            error.addClass("errorMessages");
        }

    });

})
```

Comment: Seems like a non-issue to me.  It's not normal for somebody to need/want/put an empty space after an email address.

Comment: BTW, you are missing a closing quote inside your selector here, `$("#registerForm)`.  That's why the code is displayed with funky colors in your OP.

Comment: @Sparky, I corrected the error. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`email:true` validates the input as an email. No spaces are allowed in an email adress, therefore there are errors. One way to achive what you want is to delete the `email:true` line and create a regex validation

Comment: Yes, but I mean when the email is appended with a space in the input field. I do not want the error message display when this happens. It seems the only way around this is to use regex validation.

Comment: @Nikita, exactly like he said.  A space is not allowed in an email address, _even at the end_, so it's going to fail validation.  You'd have to use a custom regex if you want to allow spaces.  Although, why would you want to do this?  It's not normal for somebody to need an empty space after an email address.

Comment: @Sparky I simply don't like the behavior, I understand emails cannot contain spaces.

Comment: @Nikita, if you understand emails can't contain spaces, they why are you expecting the `email` validation rule to behave any differently?  This answer is simply telling you that you'll need to make your own custom rule if that's what you want it to do.

Comment: @Sparky, It is a non-relevant space which could easily be stripped off before validation and entry into a data-base. If you sign up for a profile on github, for example, you may append a space to the end of the email and validation will still pass. I simply do not like the default behavior of the email validation here.

Comment: @Nikita, **yes, we understand your very unusual requirement.**  However, do you understand that you cannot use the `email` rule then?  In other words, kikyalex gave you the correct answer.  If you don't like the `email` rule, you'll need to write your own.

Comment: Yes, ***"it is a non-relevant space"***, indeed; it would and should never be typed in the first place.

Comment: @Sparky, unfortunately the internet does not work under 'woulds' and 'shoulds'

Comment: @Nikita, my point is that practically **nobody is typing extra spaces at the end.**  However, the one person who comes along someday and types a space will maybe appreciate your extra effort.